# How do I make a reference in a chart header/title?

Tags: excel, vba, charts, header, title

I'm creating a template that should get user input from a specified cell. The user will specify this after the script has run so it should be a reference. However, I do not seem to work, if I make an address it just copies the address name and does not make a reference.

I have tried to make a direct connection and putting the "=" and "='" before the address. Also tried to make the address, but no results yet.

```
Dim Np As Integer 
Dim Nj As Integer 
Dim chtname As Variant

Nj = Range("C5").Value 
Np = Range("C6").Value

chtname = "Data!" & ActiveCell.Offset(-Np - 3, 1).Address

With ActiveSheet.ChartObjects.Add _ 
(Left:=500, Width:=400, Top:=75, Height:=150) 
.Chart.SetSourceData Source:=Sheets("Data").Range(ActiveCell.Offset(-Np - 3, 8 + Nj), ActiveCell.Offset(-2, 8 + Nj)) 
.Chart.ChartType = xlXYScatterLines 
.Chart.FullSeriesCollection(1).XValues = Sheets("Data").Range(ActiveCell.Offset(-1 - Np, 7), ActiveCell.Offset(-2, 7)) 
.Chart.FullSeriesCollection(1).Name = chtname 
.Chart.SetElement (msoElementPrimaryCategoryAxisTitleAdjacentToAxis)

   End With
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are trying?

```
.Chart.HasTitle = True
.Chart.ChartTitle.Formula = "=" & chtname
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, unfortanatly is doesn't create a reference to the cell only, when I check the chart name it states ="="

Comment: It will return error 1004, and the script stops for some reason

Comment: I tested the above code. Oh I think I know why... You are using `ActiveCell`. Try selecting ay cell C25 and then run the code. If it works then you will have to amend the code

Comment: It does update the cell, but unfortunately when I type something in that particular cell it does not update the graph title